# Alternative to using frames to provide a Navigation area that can be resized by dragging

Tags: html, css, frames

I currently have an old html project that uses 3 frames side by side to display Navigation, Content and Properties.  This allows the users to expand or contract each pane so they can easily see the content if it becomes to wide.  Frames allow me to make these panes full height of the screen and allow the user to grab and resize.

I want to stop using frames as the content does not need to come from different pages, so I want to create a layout that reacts the same way as the frames do:

**3 panes displayed side by side.**

**Each pane can grabbed and made bigger or smaller (width) and the other panes will resize to fill the space.**

**Each pane will be 100% of the screen height and width.**

I've looked at iframes and they don't do that.  What is my best approach, without having to rely on jquery to do resizing or similar, is there a way to do this with a good old `div` and some good old css?

I have tried various different ways of using iframes, divs and can't find a way of doing this without using jquery to auto/resize the divs etc.

**Edit: I have to provide a solution that works in IE\Edge and also if possible work in other browsers.**

Answer (score 1):

[`resize: horizontal;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resize)

#### Drawbacks:

- It does not work with Interner Explorer/Edge ([Browser compatibility](https://caniuse.com/css-resize))
- The handle is in the corner
- without JavaScript or loading the content in an iframe the resizing will reset every time a link is clicked.

It is tricky to make the other divs use the rest of the space so i suggest using flexbox.

#### Example

http://jsfiddle.net/exLy76hu/21/

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.column {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
.resizeable {
  resize: horizontal;
}
#nav {
  width: 200px;
}
#content {
  width: 300px;
}
#properties {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="column resizeable" id="nav" style="background-color:#88f">
   nav
</div>
<div class="column resizeable" id="content" style="background-color:#ff0">
   content
</div>
<div class="column" id="properties" style="background-color:#0f0">
   properties
</div>
```

Comment: Annoyingly I have to support IE/Edge with my solution otherwise this would have been a good fit for my issue. :-(